help to grep a string from a site
I'm trying to get a spacific changing string form a site.
I used the commend:
wget -qO - www.factorio.com/download | grep '/get-download
the output is:
    wget -qO - www.factorio.com/download | grep '/get-download'
              <p>If you are running a server, you can use <a href="https://factorio.com/get-download/stable/headless/linux64">this link</a> to always download the latest stable version.
  <a href="/get-download/1.1.110/headless/linux64"
  <a href="/get-download/1.1.110/demo/win64-manual"
  <a href="/get-download/1.1.110/demo/win64"
  <a href="/get-download/1.1.110/demo/osx"
  <a href="/get-download/1.1.110/demo/linux64"

I need to get the 1.1.110 from the line:
<a href="/get-download/1.1.110/headless/linux64"

can be longer and can be shorter. but the /get-download/XXXXX/headless/linux64 is fixed.

I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

grep is not the correct tool for extracting information from HTML/XML, but it's sufficient in your case.
wget -qO - www.factorio.com/download | grep -oP '(?<=/get-download/)[0-9.]+' | uniq

This matches texts that start with /get-download/ and then contain something somewhat looking like a version number based on numbers and dots. uniq is required, because multiple version lines will be returned. The -o flag lets grep return only matches and <?= will throw away the download text after matching.
This is the result: 1.1.110

thank you very much! it worked

Small nit: you don't need to escape . in character classes (the meaning being a literal dot is implied). Also if you want to avoid bringing uniq in: wget -qO - www.factorio.com/download | sed -nE 's:.*/get-download/([0-9.]+)/headless.*:\1:p'

Thanks @kos for the feedback.

Using any version of sed:
$ wget -qO - www.factorio.com/download |
     sed -n 's:.*/get-download/\([0-9.]*\)/headless/.*:\1:p'
1.1.110

or any version of grep and cut:
$ wget -qO - www.factorio.com/download |
    grep '/get-download/[0-9.]*/headless/' | cut -d'/' -f3
1.1.110

or GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():
$ wget -qO - www.factorio.com/download |
    awk 'match($0, "/get-download/([0-9.]+)/headless/", a) { print a[1]; exit }'
1.1.110

